# Socket mirror from dynamic IP to a server

Tags: server, cloud, backend

Scenario:
I need to have access to a socket server from internet. This server is on a machine that can have a dynamic IP and can be behind router NAT etc and I don't want to configure "port forwarding" dynamic DNS for going out.

My idea is to run socket in a server that client (app) and machine with dynamic IP can connect and the server create data channel from client and master.

Master -----  Socket Mirror with DNS ---- Client (can be more than one)

what is the best way to do this? Backend service like google cloud services? or other ?

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are discussing is about to implement a `TCP tunnel`, since the question is more general I can't answer with code; I recommend services like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), where it establishes a tunnel between remote server & dynamic IP server, the software is [opensource](https://github.com/inconshreveable/ngrok).

**NOTE:** if you need answer specific to languages search with `TCP tunnel`.